# Including/importing markdown files via HTTP link

Tags: r, bookdown

We are developing content over several repositories on github and we would also like to get a book using bookdown. Is it possible to tell bookdown to include markdown files accessed via a specific http link ?

Or do we have to create a code that would download the files first on the book repo and create the book afterwards ?

Comment: Have you tried using the [`child`](https://yihui.name/knitr/options#child-documents) chunk option with an URL?

Comment: Even if you find such a method, I believe it essentially boils down to downloading. I recommend that you write a function by yourself since it shouldn't be hard (something like `cat(readLines('http://...'), sep = '\n')` or `download.file()` plus `readLines()`).

Comment: I am indeed trying now with download.file (mdfilepath,md_filename) followed by bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd") (no need of readlines). I was lucky the dependencies (images) were coded with absolute path. (https://github.com/OpenScienceMOOC/book/blob/dev_JC/Update_book.r)